# Creating HTML table with php output

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the php output into an HTML table. The mysql code outputs the data from the table pet, but when i add the table code as shown below it stops working and gives errors. How do I get the table pet output into an HTML table? thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title> php test script - hope this works </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>php & mysql connection</h1>
<hr>
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "vistor";
$db_pass = "visitor";
$db_name = "test";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pet');
echo "<table border = '2'>"
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>;
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS? I just see an HTML table, no CSS.

Comment: btw, you got two `<th>` tags and three `<td>` in each row, this may cause problems

Comment: After the query you are not closing your PHP tag and you are going directly into HTML, you must close the PHP tag before the HTML and open it again before the while statement

Comment: Fix that: `echo "</tr>;"`. Missing a `"`.

Comment: Are you sure your `$db_username` should be `vistor` and not `visitor`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issues lies in your formatting and confusion between the use of the echo command and non PHP wrapped HTML. Code should read as follows when properly formatted.

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "vistor";
$db_pass = "visitor";
$db_name = "test";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pet');
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> php test script - hope this works </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>php & mysql connection</h1>
<hr>
<table border = '2'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title> php test script - hope this works </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>php & mysql connection</h1>
 <hr>
 <?php
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_username = "vistor";
 $db_pass = "visitor";
 $db_name = "test";
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
 $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pet');
 ?>


<table border ="2">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>


<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: same as wobbles difference you can still put td and tr out of php code just echo what inside of them and close } with php

Answer (score -1):

Your quoting is wrong.

```
echo "<table border = '2'>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>";
while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The quote at the end of the first `echo` line belongs after the `</tr>`. And the last `echo "</tr>";` line was missing a closing quote.

You should be able to see these problems from the syntax highlighting in the question.

Comment: While correct; if no objects are being used in an echo, I think it is cleaner and more efficient to close the php and use normal HTML `?>My HTML code<?PHP`

Comment: @Wobbles That's a style choice.

Comment: I believe there is a performance aspect as well, echo contents are parsed through the PHP engine, non PHP wrapped code is just appended to the response. Also, most editors don't context highlight echo contents, whereas code outside PHP tags is treated like normal HTML, somthing that is helpful.

Comment: I think you'd need to have thousands of echo statements for it to make an appreciable difference.

Comment: Perhaps, but why not learn good coding habits at the most basic of levels as well as in more complex code?

Comment: I prefer to keep the style consistent. If I'm using echo statements for the variables, I also use echo statements for the literals, rather than switching in and out of PHP every few lines.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I cant get into your discussion as to which is the better option cause am still learning.