# How to include a php table in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have decoded a json in php code, so with my code I will have a php array.
How to include this array in my main html file ?

This is my php code:

```
<?php

    require_once("../main.html");
    $x=$_POST["x"];
    $y=$_POST["y"];
    $z=$_POST=["z"];
    $string=file_get_contents("............");
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($json_a,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            echo "$key:\n";
        } else {
           echo "$key => $val\n";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why not just write a loop to echo it in HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038037/creating-html-table-with-php-output

Comment: Can you post an example of the json string.

Comment: {"status":"ok","taille":1,"data":[{"id":"62215005","latitude":50.97853836,"longitude":2.04248008,"pop":"R","cp":"62215","adresse":"PLACE DU GENERAL DE GAULLE","ville":"OYE PLAGE","automate24":0,"marque":null,"nom":null,"prix":[{"idCarburant":"1","libelleCarburant":"Gazole","maj":"2019-01-22 07:50:38","valeur":"1.429"},{"idCarburant":"2","libelleCarburant":"SP95","maj":"2019-01-22 07:50:38","valeur":"1.469"},"services":[]}],"args":{"commune":"Oye-plage","carburants":"2,6","rayon":1},"time":"27-02-2019 09:00:36"}